# Book for Blowing up

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, schemes

I'm looking for a book for blowing up in algebraic geometry. I prefer those for beginners containing enough details and plenty of computable concrete examples.

In Hartshorne, there are a lot of examples of blowing up throughout the book. But, in my opinion, most of them are not in detail. He only sketches how to compute blowing up, strict transform, and some intersection properties. And I always feel difficult to fill the details.

Comment: I like the explanation given in the book by Görtz and Wedhorn.

Comment: Vakil has a chapter on blowing up. There is also a lot of material on blowing up in Eisenbud, Harris.